# Google Webmaster Tool: “Severe health issues are found on your site”

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, magento

I just saw the "Severe health issues are found on your site. Is robots.txt blocking important pages?"
 message on Google Webmaster Tools.

This is what I have in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /*?p=
Allow: /index.php/blog/
Allow: /catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
Allow: /catalogsearch/result/
Allow: /media/
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/
Disallow: /contents/
Disallow: /contents/fr/
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?p=*&
Disallow: /*?SID= 
Disallow: /*?limit=all
```

I copied this from Magento's default robots.txt and I added some folders that don't need to be indexed.

Comment: First thing, I can't believe that you have cron ah publicly available. Or in fact any config/installation scripts. Your opening yourself to getting hacked

Comment: @LiamSorsby - It's Magento, it's special... Everything is loaded in the htdocs folder system. And protected by .htaccess files. Make your judgement on running Magento for your ecommerce website from that or any other Zend framework application for that matter.

Comment: Just because it is magento, doesn't meant it is special it's a well known fact if you leave an executable file on the server that is publicly accessible, someone will find a glitch and hack it.

Comment: @LiamSorsby - preaching to the choir on this one... You should have inhabited the MagentoCommerce forums in the day when they had traffic. Every so often some web store owner would post in breathless amazement on how they'd cured a problem by deleting one of the .htaccess files. Guess what that enables? No Sarcasm markup for the **it's special** dig on stackexchange. ;^)

Comment: Not sure if it's just me but that just doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google gives you that message when it finds out that many pages on your site that it had been indexing are now all blocked in `robots.txt`.    Whether or not that message is legitimate for you depends on whether you actually want those blocked pages crawled.

I'm not specifically familiar with Magento, but the following blocked URLs seem like they might contain important content that you want indexed in search engines:

```
Disallow: /contents/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /newsletter/
```

In addition to checking that those aren't disallowed by mistake you should:

- Run a `site:example.com` search on Google and see what they have indexed.  Check to make sure there isn't anything important that is now blocked by `robots.txt`
- Examine the URLs in your sitemap.   Nothing in your sitemap should be blocked by `robots.txt`
- Use Google Webmaster Tool's "Fetch as Google" tool to make sure that they can actually download some URLs that shouldn't be blocked.

---

I would advise against disallowing the crawling of all JavaScript and CSS files.   You should remove the `Disallow: /*.js$` and `Disallow: /*.css$`.   Google has said that they really want to be able to render your pages.   They do so for screenshot as well and ranking purposes.   Your site may not rank as well if they can't do this.